# Taylor theorem approximation

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, estimation

$$e^x = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}  + \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}e^{c_x}$$

is given based on Taylor's theorem. Where $$ c_x \in [0,x] $$

I understand that the statement below is true by Taylor's theorem approximation

$$e^x  \approx \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!} $$

However, I don't understand the statement below can be approximated based on the equation above.

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^x-1}{x} dx \approx \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i*i!} $$

How do you prove this approximation statement?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^x-1}{x} dx &\approx \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}-1}{x} dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}-1}{x} dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x^{i-1}}{i!} dx \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{i-1}}{i!} dx \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i\cdot i!} dx \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Write the function $f$ as a power series and integrate term by term.

---

Notes.

It follows from $e^x\approx\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}$ that
$$
\frac{e^x-1}{x}\approx\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}
$$